# Use SMTP Protocol in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, smtp

i am using SMTP protocol for sending mail from my iphone app. but i am not clear about the functionality.

is there any document for it to understand process or how to implement it in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete example of doing it on google code.

**[Quick SMTP client code for the iPhone](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage)**

Comment: yes , it is okay but i need documentation.

Comment: i have all the codes but i need documentation